# Pentomino tiling on wrap-around 5x5 grids

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, combinatorics, tiling, polyomino

It is known that P pentominoes cannot tile a 5x5 square board.

**Q1:** If the east and west edges of the 5x5 square board are "wrapping around" (if you move a piece through one of the edges, the part appears on the opposite edge), can you tile it with P pentominoes?

**Q2:** In addition to the above, the north and south edges are also wrapping around (thus forming a toroidal surface). Can you tile it with P pentominoes?

**Q3:** Identify all distinct pentominoes that can tile the 5x5 toroidal board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q1: Here is a perhaps not elegant but at least not super ugly proof that it is

> not possible:

> Assume to reach a contradiction that we have a tiling. Consider all pentos in the tiling that touch the bottom edge. Observe that any such pento has at least 2 squares in the 4th row (1st is top 5th is bottom). As there are only 5 squares available there can be no more than 2 pentos touching the bottom.

> Because these pentos need to cover the bottom row it must be 2 and one must have its 3-long side hugging the bottom. The other must contribute 2 more meaning that these 2 pentos cover at maximum 1 square in the middle row.

> As the same argument holds for the top we have with 4 pentos spent no more than 2 of the 5 middle row squares covered. As the last pento can cover no more than 3 it must be 3 from the last pento and 1 from the top pair and 1 from the bottom pair. However, with 3 squares of the last pento aligned to the middle row the remaining 2 can only either both go up or both go down. In either case we have a 9-to-11 imbalance of squares occupied in the top 2 and bottom 2 rows. Contradiction.

Q3 (includes Q2): These are tilings for

> all but U,F and T. Color follows wrap-around.
>  [image]

Comment: Accepted this answer because it answers all three parts, but [Bass's proof for Q1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/105691/71652) and [Jaap's proof for Q1-2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105688/pentomino-tiling-on-wrap-around-5x5-grids#comment298575_105691) are also worth reading.

Comment: @Bubbler agreed.

Answer (score 6):

Paul did [the hard parts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/105690/36023), so here's the answer to Q1:

> It's impossible. To cut down the number of variations, we can chop the leg off of all the P-pentominoes, and show that it's impossible to fit 5 square tetrominoes onto the board:
>
>  As long as we cannot cross the top boundary, nothing can be gained by *not* placing two of the squares along the top. Since the sides loop, there's essentially only one way to do that. This leaves a 5x3 strip, which is not tall enough for two squares, and not wide enough for three.
>  [image]

(EDIT: while I was creating the pretty but oh so unnecessary picture, Paul edited his answer to include a solution to Q1 too. Mine seems somewhat more straightforward, so I'm leaving it up for now at least.)

Comment: Great idea chopping off the nose! Can you explain why your argument doesn't work for torus? (Sorry, always nitpicking.)

Comment: @PaulPanzer well, surely the part about "As long as we cannot cross the top boundary" won't apply to a torus, so there could, *in theory*, be something that's gained by not placing (any) two squares side by side :-)

Comment: With the 2x2 squares, there will be exactly 5 uncovered little squares. Every row and every column must have exactly one of those. This forces the placement of the 2x2 squares (up to translation/reflection).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis now there's a clean argument!